# Where could I buy the notebook that looks like the real Death Note?

Tags: death-note, merchandise

Well... I just saw the notebook in my fellow schoolmate and he just brought it to school yesterday. And I'm really curious *where he got that* and *how much did it cost*.

Comment: Well, it's a tough question to answer, especially if you don't provide with where you live. Also, asking your friend where he got it might be a better option.

Comment: It would help to specify whether you are searching for a licensed collectible or whether you are open to purchasing a non-official fan-made item such as a cosplay prop.

Comment: Please **be aware** that [you can be arrested, expelled, or suspended](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2010-03-26/michigan-middle-school-boy-suspended-over-death-note) for carrying, or writing names in, a _Death Note_-style notebook. [Cases of copycat crimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note#Copycat_crimes_and_imitations) have resulted in bans and legal action in numerous countries.

Comment: @seijitsu For the record, the link you posted only mentions the USA as a country banning or legally acting upon owning a Death Note. The case from Belgium was different in the fact that they actually murdered someone and it wasn't even a DN-inspired murder. They just added the notes "for fun" **after** the murder was committed. Whatever notebook you would use is never important, it is what you write in it that matters. So not sure what you mean with *numerous countries*.

Comment: @Peter Raeves, by "numerous countries" I was also thinking of cases beyond the ones listed in those 2 links, such as the cases of China and Russia mentioned in this [news article](http://www.japantoday.com/category/entertainment/view/parents-in-russia-request-ban-on-death-note) from _The Japan Times_.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these links:

http://www.399animeshop.com/anime/death-note/death-note-book-replica-size.php
http://www.ebay.com/bhp/death-note-notebook

There are different types tho, one type with only the cover looking like the death note, the content is like a normal notebook. The other type is exact replica, figure out which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get one might be going to a convention (gaming or anime). I don't know where you're from but I got my Death Note replica at the GamesCom (Germany). As Death Note is a really popular anime, you'll find a lot of it on conventions, not only the notebook itself.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the other answers, they are also available at [Aliexpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20150610144043&SearchText=death+note+notebook) or [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2/189-8457276-2810964?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=death+note+notebook). They even throw in a feather pen for you to make it even more real.

So my guess would be, that you would be best off going to your favourite online webshop and search for *death note notebook* and you will find what you were looking for.